# Need help from an Example of Click to Edit text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an example what I got from asking a question here in Stack overflow (Sorry I am new here this is my 2nd question )

Here is the link of that Example :

jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Pnr3P/

You Will see there have an option for clicking a button and creating a new div with re-nameable texts .This is great already .But I want to add something extra here and if can then it will be great . What I want is : If I create a div with two same name like : if I previously created a div named : "COOL" and if I created a new one, name "Cool" again it will show an warning "This name is Already taken Try new name " .

Is this possible ?? IT will be great if can be done .

Thanks in advance . All the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 $("#results").on("blur", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
 //  tells the browser, when user clicks away from input, hide input and show span
 //  also replaces text in span with new text in input

      var ok = true;
      var myinput = this;
      $('#results .new-folder .title-inp').each(function(index,input){
          if(myinput != input 
             && $(input).val().toUpperCase() == $(myinput).val().toUpperCase())
          {
              ok = false;
              return false;
          }
      });

      if(ok) $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
      else   alert('repeated name!');
 });
```

Hope it helps!

The working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Wbrj3/4/

Comment: It's great it helps you :)